# How does one make a Hadran on two Masechtos?

Tags: talmud-gemara, siyum

I'm almost finished with learning Shavuos and Bava Metzia side by side, and I was going to make a siyum on the two of them together. That got me thinking: what should I do about a Hadran? You name the Masechtos in both the opening paragraph and the later Yehi Ratzon. Do I stick in both places both names of both Masechtos? Do I stick in both names only in one place and say the other paragraph twice? Do I make the entire Hadran twice?

Comment: יישר כוח I HOPE YOU WILL LEARN STRONGLY

Comment: Daniel, Mazal Tov on completing all of that learning! To determine how you, personally, should proceed with your siyum, I recommend that you consult your rabbi.

Comment: It is as seder Kaparot. conjugation: Lo nitntshe minechon massechet A and massechaet B ve lo titneshe minan..

Comment: No source, just a thought. It is impossible to finish both tractates simultaneously. You will finish first one and then the other. I would think you would finish the first one, say the hadran and kaddish, and then do the second one. This is similar to those who say kaddish after each book of tehillim.

Comment: This may seem like a strange idea. But, I think that each masechta deserves its own siyum. After all, there is a reason why a meschat is created in the first place. It concentrates (mostly) on a single topic, and desreves its own "respect". So why not make 2 siyumim one after the other? All it requires is benching, rewashing the hands, making another hamotzi and another Hadran. It really doesn't take that long to do that.

Comment: @DanF Finishing a meal intending to start another in the same place is almost certainly s problem of _b'racha sheenah tz'richa_. There may be something to splitting them, though, a la _en m'ar'vin simcha v'simcha_.

Comment: @Menachem: I'm learning them side by side, in different Bein HaSedarim. I'll probably finish them both around the same time, and, as per msh210's point, I don't see it as an ein me'arvin simcha b'simcha issue since, although they're two different mesechtos, I'm learning them together and thus am making a siyum on that "unit."

Comment: @Menachem it is perhaps not necessary to finish at the same instant.

Comment: @msh210 Making two se'udot one following the other, is done in a few cases. Most notably, when Erev Pesach is on Shabbat. Many rabbanim suggest the exact procedure that I mentioned. Apparently, there  is no problem with "bracha she'eno tzricha". As for mixing two simchot - I'm not sure how that applies. You finished one siyum for one masechta. That's one simcha. You make a siyum and hadran for another masechta. That's its own simcha. As a matter of fact, I would see this problem of "ein me'arvin" more likely if you DIDN"T make a separate siyum, using this logic.

Comment: @memachem who says kaddish after books of tehillim? Sounds fishy as we aren't supposed to add kaddishes. Sounds like a modern innovation of mourners who think Kaddish trumps everything.

Comment: @danf That is false. On erev pesach on shabbat you take a break between meals to avoid this issue. It is an issue.

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1661&st=&pgnum=43 https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20085&st=&pgnum=321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

הַדְרָן עֲלָייכי מַסֶּכֶת **ב"ק__ומסכת_שבועות** וְהַדְרָייכי עֲלָן, דַּעְתָּן עֲלייכי מַסֶּכֶת **ב"ק_ומסכת_שבועות_** וְדַעְתָּיכי עֲלָן, לָא נִתְנְשֵׁי מִנָּייכו מַסֶּכֶת **ב"ק ומסכת שבועות_** וְלָא תִתְנְשִׁו מִנָּן, לָא בְּעָלְמָא הָדֵין וְלָא בְּעָלְמָא דְאָתֵי:
יאמר כן שלש פעמים ואחר כך יאמר זה:‏

יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶיךָ יְיָ אֱלֹהֵינוּ וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתֵינוּ, שֶׁתְּהֵא תוֹרָתְךָ אֻמָּנוּתֵנוּ בָּעוֹלָם הַזֶּה, וּתְהֵא עִמָּנוּ לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא. חֲנִינָא בַּר פַּפָּא, רָמֵי בַּר פַּפָּא, נַחְמָן בַּר פַּפָּא, אֲחַאי בַּר פַּפָּא, אַבָּא מָרִי בַּר פַּפָּא, רַפְרָם בַּר פַּפָּא, רָכִישׁ בַּר פַּפָּא, סוּרְחַב בַּר פַּפָּא, אַדָּא בַּר פַּפָּא, דָּרוּ בַּר פַּפָּא:‏

הַעֲרֶב- נָא, יְיָ אֱלֹהֵינוּ, אֶת דִּבְרֵי תוֹרָתְךָ בְּפִינוּ וּבְפִיפִיּוֹת עַמְּךָ בֵית יִשְׂרָאֵל, וְנִהְיֶה אֲנַחְנוּ וְצֶאֱצָאֵינוּ (וְצֶאֱצָאֵי צֶאֱצָאֵינוּ) וְצֶאֱצָאֵי עַמְּךָ בֵית יִשְׂרָאֵל, כֻּלָּנוּ יוֹדְעֵי שְׁמֶךָ וְלוֹמְדֵי תוֹרָתְךָ לִשְׁמָהּ. מֵאֹיְבַי תְּחַכְּמֵנִי מִצְוֹתֶךָ כִּי לְעוֹלָם הִיא לִי: יְהִי לִבִּי תָמִים בְּחֻקֶּיךָ לְמַעַן לֹא אֵבוֹשׁ: לְעוֹלָם לֹא אֶשְׁכַּח פִּקּוּדֶיךָ כִּי בָם חִיִּיתָנִי: בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה יְיָ לַמְּדֵנִי חֻקֶּיךָ: אָמֵן אָמֵן אָמֵן סֶלָה וָעֶד:‏

מוֹדִים אֲנַחְנוּ לְפָנֶיךָ יְיָ אֱלֹהֵינוּ וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתֵינוּ שֶׁשַּׂמְתָּ חֶלְקֵנוּ מִיּוֹשְׁבֵי בֵּית הַמִּדְרָשׁ-וְלֹא שַׂמְתָּ חֶלְקֵנוּ מִיּוֹשְׁבֵי קְרָנוֹת. שֶׁאָנוּ מַשְׁכִּימִים וְהֵם מַשְׁכִּימִים, אָנוּ מַשְׁכִּימִים לְדִבְרֵי תוֹרָה-וְהֵם מַשְׁכִּימִים לִדְבָרִים בְּטֵלִים. אָנוּ עֲמֵלִים וְהֵם עֲמֵלִים, אָנוּ עֲמֵלִים וּמְקַבְּלִים שָׂכָר-וְהֵם עֲמֵלִים וְאֵינָם מְקַבְּלִים שָׂכָר. אָנוּ רָצִים וְהֵם רָצִים, אָנוּ רָצִים לְחַיֵּי הָעוֹלָם הַבָּא-וְהֵם רָצִים לִבְאֵר שָׁחַת, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: וְאַתָּה אֱלֹהִים תּוֹרִדֵם לִבְאֵר שַׁחַת אַנְשֵׁי דָמִים וּמִרְמָה לֹא יֶחֱצוּ יְמֵיהֶם וַאֲנִי אֶבְטַח בָּךְ:‏

יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶיךָ יְיָ אֱלֹהַי, כְּשֵׁם שֶׁעֲזַרְתַּנִי לְסַיֵּם מַסֶּכֶת **ב"ק__ומסכת __שבועות**, כֵּן תַּעַזְרֵנִי לְהַתְחִיל מַסֶּכְתּוֹת וּסְפָרִים אֲחֵרִים וּלְסַיְּמָם, לִלְמֹד וּלְלַמֵּד לִשְׁמֹר וְלַעֲשׂוֹת וּלְקַיֵּם אֶת כָּל דִּבְרֵי תַלְמוּד תּוֹרָתְךָ בְּאַהֲבָה, וּזְכוּת כָּל הַתַּנָּאִים וְאָמוֹרָאִים וְתַלְמִידֵי חֲכָמִים יַעֲמֹד לִי וּלְזַרְעִי שֶׁלֹּא תָמוּשׁ הַתּוֹרָה מִפִּי וּמִפִּי זַרְעִי וְזֶרַע זַרְעִי עַד עוֹלָם, וְיִתְקַיֵּם בִּי: בְּהִתְהַלֶּכְךָ תַּנְחֶה אֹתָךְ בְּשָׁכְבְּךָ תִּשְׁמֹר עָלֶיךָ וַהֲקִיצוֹתָ הִיא תְשִׂיחֶךָ: כִּי בִי יִרְבּוּ יָמֶיךָ וְיוֹסִיפוּ לְּךָ שְׁנוֹת חַיִּים: אֹרֶךְ יָמִים בִּימִינָהּ בִּשְׂמֹאולָהּ עֹשֶׁר וְכָבוֹד: יְיָ עֹז לְעַמּוֹ יִתֵּן יְיָ יְבָרֵךְ אֶת עַמּוֹ בַשָּׁלוֹם:‏

יִתְגַּדַּל וְיִתְקַדַּשׁ שְׁמֵהּ רַבָּא. בְּעָלְמָא דְּהוּא עָתִיד לְאִתְחַדְּתָא, וּלְאַחֲיָא מֵתַיָּא, וּלְאַסָּקָא לְחַיֵּי עָלְמָא, וּלְמִבְנֵי קַרְתָּא דִּירוּשְׁלֵם, וּלְשַׁכְלֵל הֵיכְלֵהּ בְּגַוַּהּ, וּלְמֶעְקַר פּוּלְחָנָא נוּכְרָאָה מֵאַרְעָא, וְלַאֲתָבָא פּוּלְחָנָא דִשְׁמַיָּא לְאַתְרֵהּ, וְיַמְלִיךְ קֻדְשָׁא בְרִיךְ הוּא בְּמַלְכוּתֵהּ וִיקָרֵיהּ (נ"ס: וְיַצְמַח פּוּרְקָנֵהּ וִיקָרֵב מְשִׁיחֵהּ). בְּחַיֵּיכוֹן וּבְיוֹמֵיכוֹן וּבְחַיֵּי דְכָל בֵּית יִשְׂרָאֵל, בַּעֲגָלָא וּבִזְמַן קָרִיב, וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן:
יְהֵא שְׁמֵהּ רַבָּא מְבָרַךְ לְעָלַם וּלְעָלְמֵי עָלְמַיָּא.‏
יִתְבָּרַךְ וְיִשְׁתַּבַּח וְיִתְפָּאַר וְיִתְרוֹמַם וְיִתְנַשֵּׂא וְיִתְהַדַּר וְיִתְעַלֶּה וְיִתְהַלָּל שְׁמֵהּ דְּקֻדְשָׁא בְרִיךְ הוּא. לְעֵלָּא (בעשי"ת לְעֵלָּא לְעֵלָּא מִכָּל) מִן כָּל בִּרְכָתָא וְשִׁירָתָא תֻּשְׁבְּחָתָא וְנֶחֱמָתָא דַּאֲמִירָן בְּעָלְמָא. וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן:‏
עַל יִשְׂרָאֵל וְעַל רַבָּנָן וְעַל תַּלְמִידֵיהוֹן וְעַל כָּל תַּלְמִידֵי תַלְמִידֵיהוֹן, וְעַל כָּל מַאן דְּעָסְקִין בְּאוֹרַיְתָא, דִּי בְּאַתְרָא קַדִּישָׁא הָדֵין וְדִי בְּכָל אֲתַר וַאֲתַר, יְהֵא לְהוֹן וּלְכוֹן שְׁלָמָא רַבָּא, חִנָּא וְחִסְדָּא וְרַחֲמִין, וְחַיִּין אֲרִיכִין וּמְזוֹנֵי רְוִיחֵי, וּפוּרְקָנָא, מִן קֳדָם אֲבוּהוֹן דְּבִשְׁמַיָּא וְאַרְעָא, וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן:‏
יְהֵא שְׁלָמָא רַבָּא מִן שְׁמַיָּא וְחַיִּים טוֹבִים עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל, וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן:‏
עוֹשֶׂה שָׁלוֹם (בעשי"ת הַשָּׁלוֹם) בִּמְרוֹמָיו, הוּא יַעֲשֶׂה שָׁלוֹם עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל, וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן:‏

‏

An other   eventuality is to say 2 X:

> הֲדָרָן עֲלָךְ מַסֶּכֶת {{{בבא קמא}}} וַהֲדָרָךְ עֲלָן. דַּעְתָּן עֲלָךְ מַסֶּכֶת {{{בבא קמא}}} וְדַעְתָּךְ עֲלָן. לֹא נִתְנְשֵׁי מִנָּךְ מַסֶּכֶת {{{בבא קמא}}} וְלֹא תִתְנְשֵׁי מִנָּן לָא בְּעָלְמָא הָדֵין וְלָא בְּעָלְמָא דְּאָתֵי:‏
>
> הֲדָרָן עֲלָךְ מַסֶּכֶת {{{שבועות}}} וַהֲדָרָךְ עֲלָן. דַּעְתָּן עֲלָךְ מַסֶּכֶת {{{שבועות}}} וְדַעְתָּךְ עֲלָן. לֹא נִתְנְשֵׁי מִנָּךְ מַסֶּכֶת {{{שבועות}}} וְלֹא תִתְנְשֵׁי מִנָּן לָא בְּעָלְמָא הָדֵין וְלָא בְּעָלְמָא דְּאָתֵי:‏

...

> ‏    יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶיךָ יְיָ אֱלֹהַי, כְּשֵׁם שֶׁעֲזַרְתַּנִי לְסַיֵּם מַסֶּכֶת {{{בבא קמה}}} ‏ , כְּשֵׁם שֶׁעֲזַרְתַּנִי לְסַיֵּם מַסֶּכֶת {{{שבועות}}} ‏

...

Comment: Do you have a source for this formulation?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I have no source, more, I am not truly know aramean grammar, but I ame sure that there is no other possibilities. The Sium of Sefer Tehilim is very similar. See [here](http://tehilim.co/pray-after#c2)

Comment: This was one of the possibilities I had raised in my question ("stick in both places both names of both Mesechtos"); I wasn't sure if it was the correct one, however. Like Isaac, I'd like to see a source if this is indeed what to do in this situation.

Comment: @IsaacMoses is there an idea about some problem, as mitsvot chavilot or so what?

Comment: Just confirmed with my LOR that the first version, changing all of the singular pronouns to plural, is indeed the correct way to go. As per the discussion in the comments to my original question, there's no issue of ein me'arvin simcha b'simcha. He didn't give me a reason, however.

Comment: This site is meant to accomedate English speakers. Consider adding a short summary of the relevant changes.

Comment: The op want a nussach, I give a nussach